# How can serialize and send a MailMessage over a WCF Web Service?

Tags: c#, web-services, serialization, mailmessage

I want to pass a MailMessage as a parameter to my WCF Web Service. The problem is MailMessage is not serializable and a lot of it's properties, such as MailAddress, are not serializable either. How do I serialize it?

I've seen a [tutorial](http://keyvan.io/how-to-serialize-a-mailmessage) for serializing it by using it as a property in a wrapper class, but that doesn't help me send it over WCF because the MailMessage property doesn't show up on the client side (because it's not serializable). I don't want to just send basic string values (to, from, body). I want to send the entire MailMessage and all its properties. How can I do this?

**Update:**

I decided it's simply not worth it to use a Web Service and serialize the MailMessage class. The serialization classes did work, but a lot of their methods/constructors weren't available on the WCF client/consumer. So I had to re-write the code to convert from the regular class (e.g. MailMessage) to the serialized class (e.g. SerializedMailMessage) on the client side.

I've decided to create a class library with an EmailHelper and use the calling app's config to determine the SMTP settings.

```
SmtpSection smtpConfig = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp") as SmtpSection;
if (smtpConfig != null) {
    // extract values to your SmtpClient
}
```

Comment: check this out.. it is a reasonable approach...
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447071/can-i-pass-a-system-net-mailmessage-to-a-wcf-service][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447071/can-i-pass-a-system-net-mailmessage-to-a-wcf-service

Comment: I saw those questions, but the problem is the properties of the MailMessage such as MailAddress, are not serializable as well. I guess I'll just remake the entire class and the classes of it's properties as serializable classes. What I'd prefer is a way to extend the class and make it serializable in that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to make a Serializeable version of the MailMessage class and make Serializeable classes for each of it's properties (e.g. MailAddress, Attachment...).

Luckily, I found this free open source code (Composite C1 Contrib by burning ice) that has already done all that:

[Source Code](https://bitbucket.org/burningice/compositec1contrib/src/bce3ed2614bb/Email/Serialization)

[License Details](http://compositec1contrib.codeplex.com/license)